# How to build CS50 programs with make

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make, cs50

I am trying to study cs50 on linux , I downloaded everything I found on github, but now I can not compile my first program with make, but I can use clang instead `clang hello.c -lcs50 -o hello` which works just fine, but when I try to compile with `make hello` I get

```
:~/cs50/pset1# make hello
cc     hello.c   -o hello
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczILfhu.o: in function 'main':
hello.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to 'get_string'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: hello] Error 1
```

I even moved the libcs50 folder that I downloaded to /usr/include/ 
but I still get the same results.
after I compile with clang , and then excute `make hello` it says
make: 'hello' is up to date.
I know it sounds dump but I am still newbie and looking for help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a `Makefile` in the source directory to instruct `make` *how* to build `hello`?  The command you show it using is exactly what it would do if forced to guess.

Comment: no , I dont , how can I do that please ?

Comment: That's too broad a question.  The general answer fills a book (the `make` manual).  If CS50 has you using `make` then it surely covers the construction of `Makefile`s well enough to get you by.

Comment: A useful search phrase for your favorite search engine might be *what is a makefile*.

Comment: as you can see, `make hello` does not know how to build the `hello` executable - and is using the *implicit rule* that uses the *`cc`* compiler command, without the `-lcs50` which is required here. How'd it know otherwise?

Comment: I searched youtube for this , why do I havr to do it while I am still a newbie and starting cs50? shouldnt I be able to compile with make by default ?

Comment: You should show us your makefile. Please [edit] your question and put your makefile _there_ not into a comment.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala on the course, I could  do that by default on the cloud, but my directory only contained hello.c in it and then when I compile , a compiled file named hello is there, and then I can excute using ./hello

Comment: @Jabberwocky I dont have a Makefile, I was not told to create that on the course , I am still on week1 of cs50

Comment: @HFBrowning, I am and ts working fine on their IDE, but I am trying to learn linux aswell so I am tryng locally , and it is not that hard look at Antti 's answer <3

Comment: There's a [cs50 stack exchange](http://cs50.stackexchange.com/) if you're interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For linking in the cs50 library (which you should have installed from https://github.com/cs50/libcs50 according to the instructions there), your linking command should specify the `-lcs50` argument.

`make` usually needs a `Makefile` to control the build. In its absence it can use some implicit rules to guess the build process, like that `hello.o` could be built from `hello.c` and `hello` could be linked from `hello.o` and so forth, but it certainly cannot guess that `libcs50` should be linked in.

Fortunately, the implicit linking rules include the contents of the variable `LDLIBS` in the correct, so you can fix this by writing a simple `Makefile` in the same directory, containing just

```
LDLIBS += -lcs50
```

I.e. "append the string `-lcs50` to the current value of `LDLIBS`".

After that `make hello` will use the implicit rules *and* the new value of `LDLIBS` to execute

```
cc     hello.c  -lcs50 -o hello
```

Also do note that the `cc` command usually is GCC, not Clang, not that it should matter in CS50. It can be configured with the `CC` variable in `Makefile`:

```
CC := clang
```

Finally, it does make sense to enable warnings and pedantry in the *compilation* flags, for example:

```
CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c11
```

With all these 3 present, `make hello` will actually execute

```
clang -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c11    hello.c  -lcs50 -o hello
```

which means we did save quite a lot typing and get more useful diagnostics!

---

Of course for a more complicated build process you'd need to write a more complicated `Makefile` with dependency rules - say if your `helloworld` program consisted of `hello.c` and `world.c` linked together you could get by the implicit rules and just state that `helloworld` depends on both *`hello.o`* and *`world.o`* and should be linked together from these:

```
helloworld: hello.o world.o
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)

# the command *must* be indented by a *single* tab character, not spaces!
# unfortunately SO editor does not make it easy to write tabs.
```

Comment: Thanks Antti , you're a life saver :)

Comment: I did it immediately but It wont show publicly because I dont have enough reputation yet sorry.

Comment: @DiaaAlaa you upvoted, you didn't [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/190417).

Comment: as I said, still newbie, in an embarrassing way now :D

Comment: @DiaaAlaa - We all started from the same place. Best advise is to just slow down -- there is a lot to learn, pay attention to the details of C, and the tools like `make`. Learning is more a journey than a race - it's not something you someday finish. Soon that newbie feeling will start to fade.

Answer (score 0):

Just make new **Makefile** in the *dir* where is your *.c file:

$ `touch Makefile`

Then just add this strings to your Makefile:

```
CC=clang
CFLAGS=-fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow
LDLIBS=-lcrypt -lcs50 -lm
```

Than you can compile *.c file just typing:

$ `make hello.c`